# Is the way Chrome changes the history after a Google search a cause for concern?

Tags: security, google-chrome

In all versions of Chrome you can use the address bar as a shortcut to jump straight to a google search result for your query.

I have just noticed in Chrome (20.0.1132.47 for Mac) that when I type a search query in the address bar and get the results *and then hit the history back button* that I am now taken to the Google homepage, with my query pre-written in the textbox.

Example: If I start on an page, then type "how to upload to imgur" into the address bar, I'm taken straight to here:
[image]
Then, when I press the back button I'm taken to this page:
[image]

Is this a new feature of Chrome, or have I just been blind to it for ages? I'm 90% sure that it didn't do this before.

My real question though is this: How is this accomplished? How can you trick the browser into thinking that you've been to a page that you haven't, and isn't this a security concern?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My chrome (same version, also Mac) doesn't do this. I also tested this on the Canary build (currently 22) and it also doesn't have this behaviour.

Maybe it's something google.com (rather than chrome) are trialing?

Chrome loads these search results from the omnibox (address bar) in a background/hidden tab and then brings the tab in to view when you hit enter so anything that happens in the browser window is something google.com is doing, and not chrome it's self.

As for how it's accomplished, likely it's the HTML History API, which you can read about here: http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html

Comment: I guess that must be it. The functionality has come and gone over the last couple of weeks so I think you're right. I wasn't aware that the history api could be used to push items onto the stack as if you had been there already. So I learned something new!